# Reading Integer values from a file (Java)

Tags: java, file, file-io, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a simple level editor for my Android game.  I've written the GUI (which draws a grid) using swing.  You click on the squares where you want to position a tile and it changes colour.  Once you're done, you write everything to a file.

My file consists of something like the following (this is just an example):

[image]

I use the asterisks to determine the level number being read and the hyphen to tell the reader to stop reading.

My file reading **code** is below, Selecting which part to read works OK - for example. if I pass in 2 by doing the following:

```
readFile(2);
```

Then it prints all of the characters in the 2nd section

What I can't figure out is, once I've got to the 'start' point, how do I actually read the numbers as *integers* and **not** individual characters?

**Code**

```
    public void readFile(int level){

        try {
                    //What ever the file path is.
                    File levelFile = new File("C:/Temp/levels.txt");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(levelFile);
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);    
                    Reader r = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    int charTest;

                    //Position the reader to the relevant level (Levels are separated by asterisks)
                    for (int x =0;x<level;x++){
                    //Get to the relevant asterisk
                    while ((charTest = fis.read()) != 42){
                     }
                    }
                    //Now we are at the correct read position, keep reading until we hit a '-' char
                    //Which indicates 'end of level information'
                    while ((charTest = fis.read()) != 45){

                    System.out.print((char)charTest);   
                    }

                    //All done - so close the file
                    r.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    System.err.println("Problem reading the file levels.txt");
                }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner's a good answer. To remain closer to what you have, use the BufferedReader to read whole lines (instead of reading one character at a time) and Integer.parseInt to convert from String to Integer:

```
// get to starting position
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(isr);
...
String line = null;
while (!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("-"))
{
  int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `BufferedReader` and not the `Reader` interface, you can call `r.readLine()`. Then you can simply use `Integer.valueOf(String)` or `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using `readLine` which gets all the chars up the the end of line.

This part:

```
for (int x =0;x<level;x++){
    //Get to the relevant asterisk
    while ((charTest = fis.read()) != 42){
    }
}
```

Can change to this:

```
for (int x =0;x<level;x++){
    //Get to the relevant asterisk
    while ((strTest = fis.readLine()) != null) {
        if (strTest.startsWith('*')) {
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to read the values another loop:

```
for (;;) {
    strTest = fls.readLine();
    if (strTest != null && !strTest.startsWith('-')) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(strTest);
        // ... you have to store it somewhere
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

You also need some code in there to handle errors including a premature end of file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have look at the Scanner API in Java.
You can have a look at their [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)